# Android get dates as long values

Tags: android, date

How do I get 11:59 PM of the previous night and 12:00 AM of tonight expressed as long values???

So many different date options I'm confused

Comment: `long` values relative to what? Do you have dates? Or do you just want how many seconds they represent? (86399 vs 0)

Comment: Based on the phone's current date get tonight at 12:00 AM and the previous night at 11:59 PM. I'm using it for a cursor so the cursor accepts long values not dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this calculation to do so.

```
//11:59 PM of the previous night and 12:00 AM of tonight 

    Calendar prevDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(prevDate.get(Calendar.DATE)==1)
    {
        if(prevDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)==0)
        {
            prevDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, prevDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1);
            prevDate.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DECEMBER);
            prevDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,31);
        }
        else
        {
            prevDate.set(Calendar.MONTH,prevDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1);
            prevDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, prevDate.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        prevDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,prevDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1);
    }

    prevDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    prevDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);

    Calendar currDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    currDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    currDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

    long prevDateLong = prevDate.getTimeInMillis();
    long currDateLong = currDate.getTimeInMillis();

    Log.i("", prevDate.toString()+" >>>>>>>> "+currDate.toString());
    Log.i("", prevDateLong+" >>>>>>>>> "+currDateLong);
```

Comment: currDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); should be currDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);

Answer (score 0):

All Java dates are longs underneath.  It's the number of milliseconds since midnight on 1-Jan-1970.

```
Date today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd").parse("2012-Oct-28");  // today at midnight
long millis = today.getTime();
```

I'd recommend that you look at the `java.util.Calendar` class.  It's not hard, just tedious.

http://www.exampledepot.com/search/luceneapi_node/Calendar

Comment: Yeah but that gets a hard coded date. I want today at 12:00 AM based on the current date of the calendar on the phone